# globalDevDependencies not working as expected

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm using Typescript 2.4.0 and have the following in my `package.json`:

```
"globalDevDependencies": {
  "chai": "^3.5.0",
  "mocha": "^3.4.2",
  "@types/chai": "^3.0.0",
  "@types/mocha": "^2.2.41"
},
```

I then have a test file `test-spec.ts` which starts out as:

```
const expect = chai.expect;
```

When I try and compile this, however, it complains that "chai is not defined". I was expecting that my global deps reference would automatically bring this into the global namespace. I also tried changing to `globalDependencies` section but that too came up with the same error.

Maybe I'm not understanding what these dependency blocks offer.

Comment: Are you confused about typings.json and package.json? Does npm has `globalDependencies'?

Comment: possibly, i am easily confused. To be honest I didn't know there _was_ a `typings.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no `globalDependencies` or `globalDevDependencies` in npm.

What you need is just installing the typings using npm:

`npm install -D @types/chai @types/mocha`

With that, you should be able to access `chai.expect` as in your example.

`@types/mocha` doesn't export itself in the global namespace.
To fix that, you need to do global augmentation similar to the following:

```
// custom-typings/mocha.d.ts
import mocha = require('mocha')
declare global {
 type describe = mocha.describe
  ...
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "custom-typings"
  ]
}
```

You may need to work on the global augmentation a bit to get it correct.
I haven't use 'mocha' for quite a while now. :)

Here is the information about global augmentation:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: that is actually what I originally had until I saw a bunch about the above sections in some Angular discussion which lead me to _thinking_ they existed but they may not. Anyway, with this in place, I get an error that "describe" is not defined when I run via `ts-node` (which I do sometimes to just validate that it compiles fine). When I run via mocha it works fine.

Comment: Updated answer regarding that. Sorry I haven't use mocha for a while, so you probably need to try it out a bit.